# what is the name of this encryption/decryption method?

Tags: asp.net, c3

this is an encryption / decryption method that i found online.....

i just want to know the name of this method

(am using asp.net c#)

```
    public string Encryptdata(string password)
    {
        string strmsg = string.Empty;
        byte[] encode = new byte[password.Length];
        encode = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(password);
        strmsg = Convert.ToBase64String(encode);
        return strmsg;
    }
    public string Decryptdata(string encryptpwd)
    {
        string decryptpwd = string.Empty;
        UTF8Encoding encodepwd = new UTF8Encoding();
        Decoder Decode = encodepwd.GetDecoder();
        byte[] todecode_byte = Convert.FromBase64String(encryptpwd);
        int charCount = Decode.GetCharCount(todecode_byte, 0, todecode_byte.Length);
        char[] decoded_char = new char[charCount];
        Decode.GetChars(todecode_byte, 0, todecode_byte.Length, decoded_char, 0);
        decryptpwd = new String(decoded_char);
        return decryptpwd;
    }
```

Comment: it's just base64, don't think this is well encryption

Comment: This is NOT an _encryption_, but _encoding_; a [base64](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) encoding